# Converting text into utf-8 in textblob

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, textblob

I have a file which i m using as my input. But it has some special characters which I need to convert it into plain text. How can I do that?

Comment: It's better if you include the code in your question instead of a comment.

Comment: You should probably decode the input text *before* you feed it into TextBlob.

Comment: Please take a tour of [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). have a look at [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) Also on how to [Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you provide an extract with the special characters?